# MySQL data provider for .net

Tags: mysql, .net

Do we have any Open Source MySql Data Provider for .net?

If any, let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you seen http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net.html

Its the offical one from MySQL.

Comment: the current version (6.2.2) is here : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/